# Constant distance from the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, templates

I have a Django application where using wkhtmltopdf I generate a pdf document. I have a section there, like the code below. I want to on each side was exactly 4 texts (objects). But everyone is different and the text comes out uneven arrangement. CSS does not help. How to do it?

```
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <h3>{% trans 'In progress' %}</h3>
    {% for worked_on in worker.worked_on.all %}
            <tr>
                <td width="33%" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="67%" class="project-name">
                    //CONTENT
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="project-image" width="33%" align="left" valign="top">
                    //CONTENT
                </td>
                <td class="project-description" valign="top">
                    //CONTENT
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="project-description" style="margin-bottom:80px;">
                        <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic content in django template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076271/dynamic-content-in-django-template)

Comment: don't ask the same question multiple times

Comment: positioning of code snipped. less scrolling needed to see the example